# midlet.platformRequest in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp

I am developing a game using j2me.  When level is completed  Im calling a url (ie: www.google.com) using **midlet.platformRequest**.In Some of **nokia** devices, it is redirected to browser, when I exit from browser, it comes back to game. But it's not working in *samsung* device.

```
 this.emidlet.platformRequest("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

how to solve this problem? Is **midlet.platformRequest** supported in all devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MIDlet.platformRequest() javadoc:](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest%28java.lang.String%29)

> **Returns:**
>   `true` if the MIDlet suite MUST first exit before the content can be fetched.

Answer (score 2):

Its OS dependent.

Whenever you call `midlet.platformRequest` then automatically control switches from app to OS browser

For Nokia devices launching browser is 1 step based (so is returned back to app).

But in some devices including Samsung it's 2-3 steps based so you need to close browser twice to return to your app.